# pivot a tibble to wide format based on multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

Here's my data:

```
game_id     team      opponent    steals    assists
       <int> <chr>     <chr>           <chr>  <chr>  
 1 401468360 Spurs     Warriors        6      18     
 2 401468360 Warriors  Spurs           9      35     
 3 401468358 Clippers  Rockets         6      25     
 4 401468358 Rockets   Clippers        11     20     
 5 401468359 Hawks     Bucks           4      23     
 6 401468359 Bucks     Hawks           4      21     
 7 401468356 Thunder   Celtics         4      21     
 8 401468356 Celtics   Thunder         15     25     
 9 401468357 Suns      Heat            9      22     
10 401468357 Heat      Suns            6      3
```

How do I get this data in the following format?

```
game_id     team     opponent     team_steals   opp_assists   team_assists   opp_steals
       <int> <chr>     <chr>          <int>       <chr>         <chr>         <chr>
 1 401468360 Spurs     Warriors        6           9              18            35
 2 401468358 Clippers  Rockets         6           11             25            20
 3 401468359 Hawks     Bucks           4           4              23            21
 4 401468356 Thunder   Celtics         4           15             21            25
 9 401468357 Suns      Heat            9           6              22            23
```

I have tried several variation of `pivot_wider` to no avail.  I'm not even sure if that function will accomplish what I am seeking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  right_join(dat, by = c("game_id", "team" = "opponent", "opponent" = "team"), 
                  suffix = c("_team", "_opponent")) %>% 
  distinct(game_id, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

```
#>     game_id     team opponent steals_team steals_opponent assists_team  assists_opponent
#> 1 401468360    Spurs Warriors           6               9           18                35
#> 2 401468358 Clippers  Rockets           6              11           25                20
#> 3 401468359    Hawks    Bucks           4               4           23                21
#> 4 401468356  Thunder  Celtics           4              15           21                25
#> 5 401468357     Suns     Heat           9               6           22                 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(game_id) %>% 
  rename(team_steals = steals) %>% 
  mutate(opp_steals = lead(team_steals)) %>% 
  rename(team_assists = assists) %>% 
  mutate(opp_assists = lead(team_assists)) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

```
    game_id team     opponent team_steals team_assists opp_steals opp_assists
      <int> <chr>    <chr>          <int>        <int>      <int>       <int>
1 401468360 Spurs    Warriors           6           18          9          35
2 401468358 Clippers Rockets            6           25         11          20
3 401468359 Hawks    Bucks              4           23          4          21
4 401468356 Thunder  Celtics            4           21         15          25
5 401468357 Suns     Heat               9           22          6           3
```

Comment: This assumes that next row is always showing the same match with team/opponent swapped. Not the best assumption.

Comment: I agree. But the data in this use case is ordered in groups of two, first is team and second is opponent. In case the structure is different we could bring it in this structure.

Comment: I would assume it's not in that specific order and use `group_by` or `arrange` (didn't give it much thought) to make your solution robust.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `pivot_wider` with some data wrangling may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr, w = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

dat |>
  group_by(game_id) |>
  mutate(foo = c("team", "opp"), across(c(team, opponent), first)) |>
  ungroup() |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = foo, values_from = c(steals, assists), names_glue = "{foo}_{.value}")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#>     game_id team     opponent team_steals opp_steals team_assists opp_assists
#>       <int> <chr>    <chr>          <int>      <int>        <int>       <int>
#> 1 401468360 Spurs    Warriors           6          9           18          35
#> 2 401468358 Clippers Rockets            6         11           25          20
#> 3 401468359 Hawks    Bucks              4          4           23          21
#> 4 401468356 Thunder  Celtics            4         15           21          25
#> 5 401468357 Suns     Heat               9          6           22           3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(game_id = c(
  401468360L, 401468360L, 401468358L,
  401468358L, 401468359L, 401468359L, 401468356L, 401468356L, 401468357L,
  401468357L
), team = c(
  "Spurs", "Warriors", "Clippers", "Rockets",
  "Hawks", "Bucks", "Thunder", "Celtics", "Suns", "Heat"
), opponent = c(
  "Warriors",
  "Spurs", "Rockets", "Clippers", "Bucks", "Hawks", "Celtics",
  "Thunder", "Heat", "Suns"
), steals = c(
  6L, 9L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 4L,
  4L, 15L, 9L, 6L
), assists = c(
  18L, 35L, 25L, 20L, 23L, 21L, 21L,
  25L, 22L, 3L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1", "2",
  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
))
```

Comment: This solution is better!

Comment: This code is also genius: `across(c(team, opponent), first)` could you please comment on this?! Removing this line will give the same intermediate result in row two, but the end result will differ containing rows with NA.

Comment: @TarJae At first I thought I could do a simple pivot_wider. However as the team and opponent name switch from the first to the second row this will not work. Hence the use  of `across(c(team, opponent), first)` so that we have the same names in each row per `game_id`. BTW: IMHO better or worse are the wrong terms. First: Create a working solution. Second: Figure out a more elegant solution on the second or the ... try. (:

Comment: Hey folks, that was the most accurate and fastest answer that I could have possibly asked for.  Thank you all for the insight and help.  I am still a noob with R but am fascinated at just how powerful it is.  Which I answer do I mark as the right one?  LOL.